# How to format a string variable to only show the first x number of characters?

Tags: formatting

I have a string variable, specifically the `emacs-version` variable that can be quite long and I am only using `message` with the first 4 of those characters.

Is there a way to format the variable in a `message` statement so that I am only printing the first x number of characters?

Right now I am using `substring` but it seems like there should be an easier / cleaner way. Please let me know if there is a more efficient way to do this:

```
(message "You are running version %s old." (substring emacs-version 0 4)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `format` tells you:

> For %s and %S, the precision specifier truncates the string to the given width.

Hence:

```el
(format "%.4s" emacs-version)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I'd recommend resorting to `emacs-major-version` and `emacs-minor-version`:

```
(message "emacs version %s.%s" emacs-major-version emacs-minor-version)
```

Comment: I wish I could select two answers.  This is actually what I want to do, but my question was about substrings so I think the other answer more accurately reflects the answer to the question.